# Move all subdirectories and their contents to the current working directory

Tags: command-line, files

I would like to know if it's possible to move all subdirectories and their contents within my working directory into the working directory, so that the subdirectories become primary directories in the tree.

for example:

I'm in `workingdir`, inside we have `folder1`, `folder2`, `folder3`, etc

now folder 1, 2, and 3 are already primary directories within the working directory, but when we get to `folder4` there is a subdirectory within which has the same name `folder4` then contents and this continues `folder5`, `folder6` onto `folder100andsomething`.

What I would like is to run a command to move the subdirectories `folder4` all the way to `folder100andsomething` along with their contents out of the parent directories, and into the working directory,
so in the end I would have `folder1` - `folder100andsomething` as primary directories and a bunch of erroneous empty parents. To clean up I can run a command to remove all the empty parent directories.

Comment: Could you not just `mv folder4/* $(pwd)`?

Comment: would that move all of the subdirectory contents as well? what about folder5-100? also in reality the names of the directories are not as simple as in the example

Comment: basically I don't want to drag and drop each subdirectory one by one, there has to be a way to do a super drag and drop on all subdirs via command line. no?

Comment: I other words in folder4, we have other folders from 1 -  100 with content in them.

Comment: NO sorry I may have been unclear. Folder4 only has subdirectory folder4 in it and this subdirectory has content. Then we have folder5 in the same working directory as folder4. Again Folder5 has subdir folder5 which has more content, then we have folder6 with subdir folder6+content, etc etc etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `find` and `rename`:

```
$ find . -mindepth 3 | rename -n 's:([^/]+)/\1:$1:'  
./folder10/folder10/blah10 -> ./folder10/blah10
./folder9/folder9/blah9 -> ./folder9/blah9
./folder8/folder8/blah8 -> ./folder8/blah8
./folder7/folder7/blah7 -> ./folder7/blah7
./folder6/folder6/blah6 -> ./folder6/blah6
./folder5/folder5/blah5 -> ./folder5/blah5
./folder4/folder4/blah4 -> ./folder4/blah4
```

The regex `([^/]+)/\1` matches text which is repeated, and has a `/` in between (so, `folder4/folder4`, etc.). The replacement is just the part which was repeated (so, just `folder4`).

The `-n` option only shows what changes will be made. If the changes look OK, then run without it to actually perform the changes.

Comment: Ok thanks muru for the answer, I ran a quick test on a small directory and for the most part it worked. The only problem is that some of the subdirectories have a slightly different name to their parent directories. In this case the regex didn't work.

Comment: @Johnny without some way to distinguish between the subfolders you want moved and other subfolders, it's going to be risky. Do you want to move all the subfolders up one level, for example, what do you do with `./folderX/folderY/fileA`?

Comment: Yeah basically I want to move all subdirectories up one level. with ./folderX/folderY/fileA I would like folderY to move up a level,  keeping it's contents, so that it's next to folderX. folderX would then be empty and I could run find . type d -empty -delete to remove the empty directory

Comment: is this possible? I can't find a command to do this

Comment: Try with a pattern like `'s:([^/]+)/([^/]+):$2:'`

Comment: I tried with the second pattern and it didn't work because the file or folder already exsisted. Just used your original pattern then moved the folders with dissimilar names manually. Thanks for the help Muru